# JS error posting to facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am trying to post to my facebook wall. I have publish_stream rights. My code looks like:

```
            //stream publish method
            function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt){
                FB.ui(
                {
                    method: 'stream.publish',
                    message: '',
                    attachment: {
                        name: name,
                        caption: '',
                        description: (description),
                        href: hrefLink
                    },
                    action_links: [
                        { text: hrefTitle, href: hrefLink }
                    ],
                    user_prompt_message: userPrompt
                },
                function(response) {
                });
            }
            function showStream(beschreibung,link){
                //FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    //console.log(response.id);
                    streamPublish(response.name,beschreibung, "orf.at",link, "Teile www.orf.at");
                //});
            }
```

and this is the error I got:
Fehler: uncaught exception: Error: http://static.ak.facebook.com wurde die Erlaubnis für das Lesen der Eigenschaft Proxy.InstallTrigger verweigert.

Did I miss anything?